# Can't add files to listbox...READ

Tags: c#, listbox, environment, appdata

I'm using a code to show all startup items in listbox with environment variable "%appdata%
There is some errors in this code that I need help with....
Check code for commented errors

Is there any other solution but still using %appdata%?

This is the code:

```
    private void readfiles()
    {
        String startfolder = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%appdata%") + "\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup";
        foldertoread(startfolder);
    }

    private void foldertoread(string folderName)
    {
        FileInfo[] Files = folderName.GetFiles("*.txt"); // HERE is one error "Getfiles"
        foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(folderName))
        {
            startupinfo.Items.Add(file.Name); // here is another error "Name"

        }
    }
```

Comment: In the future, don't just say you "have an error". It's good you pointed out what line it's on, but knowing **what the error is** is useful to those trying to help you. In this case, it's fairly obvious, but otherwise it might not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line won't work because `folderName` is a string (and does not have a `GetFiles` method):

```
FileInfo[] Files = folderName.GetFiles("*.txt");
```

The second error is occurring because the `file` variable is a `string` containing the filename.  You don't need to call `file.Name`, just try the following:

```
startupinfo.Items.Add(file);
```

Comment: The problem why I want "name" is that I only want to show the names, not the whole location+filename.extension
Another solution for that is ofcourse appreciated!

When I changed as you said i got this error..
Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'System.IO.FileInfo[]' 
on this line: FileInfo[] Files = folderName.GetFiles("*.txt");

Comment: Just use `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` on the `file` variable, like so: `startupinfo.Items.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the following line:

```
FileInfo[] Files = folderName.GetFiles("*.txt");
```

The `foreach` loop will generate what you need.
Secondly, the `file` variable is a string, so rather than calling:

```
startupinfo.Items.Add(file.Name);
```

...call instead:

```
startupinfo.Items.Add(file);
```

Finally, instead of a var type for your loop, you can use a string, and you can specify the file type filter:

```
foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles(folderName, "*.txt"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `string` object doesn't have a `GetFiles()` method. Try this:

```
string startfolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup);

string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(startfolder, "*.txt");

foreach (string file in files)
{
   startupinfo.Items.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
}
```

`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)` returns just the file name instead of full path.

Comment: Thank you! didn't know startup was an specialfolder!
Used you're code :)